# Python watchdog on network shares right issues

Tags: python, watchdog, access-rights, python-watchdog

Im using python 2.7 on Windows 7 Enterprise SP1 with watchdog to watch some network shares for file changes. I have to networkshares on the same physical (assumed Linux) host that are connected to two different subfolders. So let's say I connected to networkshare

```
Y: = //host/a
```

while the other networkshare is

```
X: = //host/b
```

I'm running a simple

```
watchmedo log --recursive
```

on both `Y:` and `X:`.In the first case I see a lot of file IO events being logged to console, in the second there is plain nothing. There should be no difference on the filesystem or anything environment related.

**Update:** I even ruled out the user access rights on the network share being the issue by connecting both drives under the same windows account.

Comment: This question doesn't contain enough information for people to give you a useful answer. When you say "it doesn't work", *what* doesn't work? What should you be seeing, and what are you seeing that's different? What is the error message? What are the access rights of the two different users you're using? Is one of those subfolders "inside" the other subfolder, or are they mounted at different locations? You haven't even told us what *operating system* you're running on: Linux? Windows? We aren't going to be able to help you with your question until you go until a LOT more details.

Comment: As pointed out in my update, I don't have ANY idea on what to look for other than the stuff I already mentioned.

Comment: those network shares are from the same host? same windows version?

Comment: As mentioned, the two shares are on the same physical machine (assumed linux) but in two different subfolders.